# How do I adjust the position of a page number on embedded pdf pages?

Tags: page-numbering, pdfpages, pagestyle

I added pdf pages, and I want them to have page numbers. So, here's what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\setboolean{@twoside}{false}
\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}, offset=5 -25]{file}
\end{document}
```

But the page numbers are positioned too high! How can I manually adjust the page number position? Here's a photo:

[image: Page number problem]

I tried fancyhdr, but it just made a line on top of my pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new page style that would identify the location of the page number for the imported pages. Below I've defined the `importedpages` page style thanks to [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{importedpages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
  \fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{-3\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\thepage}}% Lower page number into position
}

\begin{document}

Something

\includepdf[
  pages=-,% Import all pages
  noautoscale,% Don't scale pages to input
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{importedpages}}% importedpages page style for all pages
]{lipsum50.pdf}% 50 paragraphs of lorem ipsum (\lipsum[1-50])

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this, then I added \setcounter{page}{65} but there aren't any page numbers.

Comment: @user7355384: I've updated my answer to lower the page number by 3 baseline skips specifically for the imported pages. You can adjust the lowering as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly!